# Auto Scroll Text View when Talkback is enabled in Android

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, accessibility, talkback

In android, when "Talk back" is enabled and it reads text from a Overflow Scrollable TextView, it keeps on reading the entire text without scrolling. So it also reads the text that is not visible on screen.
Is there a way by which we can make the TextView to auto scroll along with the text that "Talk back" is reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The body of this answer must be 30 characters.

Seriously though, there is no way to do this.  This is a platform limitation.  You could consider chunking your text into multiple views.  This is generally more accessible as large blocks of text take a long time for TalkBack to read and can be frustrating for users.

Comment: any idea if there is a provision for it now?

Comment: In general, the ability for a TalkBack user to switch modes to read by sentence, character, I think even paragraph circumvents the need for such a feature, and your motivation to add it is only present because you aren't very good with TalkBack. Neither am I, I just work with people who are! ;)

Comment: Actually I see it happening on Gmail App. The message body scolls as you flick, so that the text you are reading is always on the screen.

Comment: "You could consider chunking your text into multiple views." from my original answer. If you open Android Device Monitor and inspect the GMail view Heirarchy you can see that GMail has done exactly this.